# I need help with how to fill out character sheets

Tags: character-creation, adnd-1e, character-sheets

My friends and I got together and decided to play first edition AD&D recently. (My friend already has AD&D 1e and we don’t want to buy new books.)

I've never played nor DMed before, but I'm supposed to DM this game and I don’t know how to do their character sheets and neither do they. We have the rolls for Charisma, Strength, Constitution, etc. But I don’t know how to work out

1. bonuses
2. modifiers
3. armour class
4. hit points
5. saving throws
6. ac adjustments
7. to hit rolls

As I’m new to D&D and roleplaying games as a whole, I don’t really understand these terms, nor have I found them in the DM handbook.

Answer (score 16):

All of the numbers you're looking for, except the last, can be found in the AD&D ***Player's Handbook***, rather than the ***Dungeon Master's Guide***. The DM is expected to be familiar with the PH as well as the DMG, and the PH material is actually more important for a starting DM.

The last part, to-hit rolls, is in a set of tables on pp.74-75 of the DMG.